# How to test for 401 redirect in e2e angular tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I have been trying to write a test to check for a redirect page from a backend api. I am expecting a 401 redirect to a login view however the tests show the page I should redirect to if I am already logged in.

I can only assume that the logged in view has already been placed in the $location.path before the call to the api and then the response is coming back after the test has finished. Is there any way to test this or am I on the right track.

My test code is:

```
window.jQueryFunction('.loginButton', 'click');
expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/Login');
```

in my app.js file I test for the 401 using angular event broadcasts

```
$rootScope.$on('event: auth-loginRequired', function() {
    window.location = '/login'
});
```

can someone tell me if I am in the right ball park or am I way off mark here.

Answer (score 0):

401 is an http error, not a redirect. Most servers send a 302 (moved permanently) but sometimes the developers change things to send a 301 (moved temporarily). Additionally, you should also be testing the value of location.path() and not window.location.